# Why this is a well defined definition? Integrals

Tags: calculus, definition

There's a definition that says that if we have $\int_{a}^{c}f = \int_{a}^{b}f + \int_{b}^{c}f$ and at least one of $\int_{a}^{b}f, \int_{b}^{c}f$ diverges, then $\int_{a}^{c}f$ diverges. Why is this well defined? for example, how do we know that there is no function $f$ such that $\int_{0}^{\infty}f = \lim_{b \to \infty} \int_{0}^{b}f$ exists (finite), but if we write it as $\int_{0}^{1}f+\int_{1}^{\infty}f$ we get that  $\int_{0}^{1}f$ diverges and therefore $\int_{0}^{\infty}f$ diverges?

EDIT: I realized the example I gave is actually impossible, but what about something like: $\int_{0}^{2}f$ converges, but both $\int_{0}^{1}f,\int_{1}^{2}f$ diverge?

Comment: This shouldn't be a definition but rather a lemma or theorem, which comes with a proof. Did you check this proof?

Comment: @Dirk No, I just read a solution to a question and they said it was by definition, and I also remember I was taught it is a definition. If it isn't, what's the proof?

Comment: There surely is some definition involved there, e.g. the fact that $f$ must be defined everywhere between $a$ and $c$; that already excludes lots of counter examples. But the fact that if one of the two on the right side diverges, so does the left side is not a definition. Unfortunately, my analysis time is too long ago to come up with the proof, but there definitely should be a proof somewhere in the lecture notes/textbook.